# wfs-t geoserver xml post request

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

I am trying to make a leaflet app that send and update point data using WFS-T, geoserver, postgis. Its a new field for me so bare with me.
I found this XML structure for the request below but I dont really understand the function of the different xml tags.

EDIT: Here is a working template for how the request should look like in an attempt to make it blindly obvious for other beginners with wfs-t

```
var postData =
        '<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:test_wfst="namespace URI" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.1.0" service="WFS" xsi:schemaLocation="namespace URI">\
            <Insert xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">\
                <layername xmlns="namespace URI">\
                    <geom xmlns="namespace URI">\
                        <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">\
                            <gml:coordinates cs="," >'+geometry+'</gml:coordinates>\
                        </gml:Point>\
                    </geom>\
                    <text xmlns="namespace URI">'+text+'</text>\
                </layername>\
            </Insert>\
        </Transaction>';
```

I have replaced http://www.domain.com/app to the one I am using. 
I just want to make sure I am on the right track and that the XML is correct?

I get a POST (403) OK error. I have not set any restrictions on authorization for the layer atm as far as I know. (WFS-T works when I use it in QGIS without authorization) Does it mean the XML is correct but somehow there is still an authorization error, or could i get the error anyway if the XML is wrong?

EDIT: Log file

```
2016-09-28 15:13:22,781 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2016-09-28 15:13:22,781 WARN [geotools.xml] - Schema location not specified as namespace/location pair. Ignoring https://www.domain.com/app (not real url)
2016-09-28 15:13:22,781 WARN [geotools.xml] - Could not find a schema
```

DescribeFeature request

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:test_wfs_edit="test_wfst" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="test_wfst">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://domain.com:80/geoserver/schemas/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd"/>
<xsd:complexType name="wfs_punkt_testType">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="id" nillable="false" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="notat" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="bol" nillable="true" type="xsd:boolean"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="verdi" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="dato" nillable="true" type="xsd:date"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="edited" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="geom" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="wfs_punkt_test" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="test_wfs_edit:wfs_punkt_testType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

JS:

```
var geometry = "63.00,23.00";

var postData = 
    '<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:skiltbase="http://www.domain.com/app" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.1.0" service="WFS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.domain.com/app">\
        <Insert xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">\
            <order xmlns="http://www.domain.com/app">\
                <geom xmlns="hhttp://www.domain.com/app">\
                    <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">\
                        <gml:coordinates cs="," >'+geometry+'</gml:coordinates>\
                    </gml:Point>\
                </geom>\
                <date xmlns="http://www.domain.com/app">'+date+'</date>\
                <id xmlns="http://www.domain.com/app">'+id+'</id>\
            </order>\
        </Insert>\
    </Transaction>';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  rooturl,
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "text/xml",
    data: postData,
    success: function(xml) {
        alert('Success!!')

        },
    success: function(xml) {
        alert('success')
        },
    error: function(xml){
        console.log('error')
        }
```

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: I added the log output in the question

Comment: what is rooturl sir, i have been tried wfs-t from one week i was unable to pass url value basically i dont know which url i have to pass

Comment: i will pass my code.. please suggest modifications sir, i have follwed http://wordpress-dbauszus.rhcloud.com/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-5/ example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the URI you asigned to the workspace instead of `https://www.domain.com/app`. The easiest way to work out what GeoServer is expecting is to execute a `describeFeatureType` request against the layer, this will give you a response like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="statesType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_NAME" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_FIPS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SUB_REGION" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STATE_ABBR" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="LAND_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WATER_KM" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PERSONS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FAMILIES" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HOUSHOLD" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WORKERS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DRVALONE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CARPOOL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PUBTRANS" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="EMPLOYED" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="UNEMPLOY" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SERVICE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MANUAL" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_MALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="P_FEMALE" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SAMP_POP" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="states" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="topp:statesType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

**UPDATE**

In my example you can see I'm asking about a feature type called "topp:states" and looking at the header the uri for `topp` is `xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"`

In your example you are looking for "test_wfs_edit:wfs_punkt_testType" and the uri is therefore `xmlns:test_wfs_edit="test_wfst"` - so your request needs to be something like:

```
 <Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:test_wfs_edit="test_wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.1.0" service="WFS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.domain.com/app">\
    <Insert xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">\
        <test_wfs_edit:wfs_punkt_test >\
            <test_wfs_edit:geom >\
                <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">\
                    <gml:coordinates cs="," >'+geometry+'</gml:coordinates>\
                </gml:Point>\
            </wfs_edit_test:geom>\
            <wfs_edit_test:date >'+date+'</wfs_edit_test:date>\
            <wfs_edit_test:id>'+id+'</wfs_edit_test:id>\
        </wfs_edit_test:order>\
    </Insert>\
</Transaction>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really useful. Will try it out and see what I get

Comment: Sorry could I ask you again which of the parameter that would be my workspace in this case? My layer I want to edit sit in my workspace "test_wfs_edit"  but that is quite different to what the Schema location is in the response (as added in question)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally got it to work, very pleased. My kml is slightly off from the one you wrote I added a template in my question to make it blindly obvious for other amateurs